# Bevel segments on bevel modifier not working properly

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges, bevel

i'm modeling a box with rigging in order to make it easier to get realistic effect but when i use the bevel modifier and increase the segments it doesn't curve the bevel edge it creates the bevel, but it keeps a straight angle and not a curved bevel.

This is the result i'm getting:
[image: The result i'm getting]

This are the bevel settings:

[image]

The intended result:

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: I figured it out. I had the bevel modifier on top of the armature modifier and when i switched the armature to que top it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the *Mitre type* to **Arc** should resolve this.  You will likely need to do this for both internal and external, but play with the settings and see what works for you.